Бот телеграм на telebot
Всем добрый день!
Пишу бот для языоковой школы, у заказчика возникла необходимость сделать воронку с вебинарами в боте. Решение где будут размещаться вебинары, пока им не сделано , я предложил в качестве одной из возможных альтернатив mts link c api c возможностью вытягивания записей вебинаров. Как я вижу этот процесс - вытянуть запись и затем разместить в бот. Но так как опыта нет -возникает вопрос о корректности подобного подхода. Может быть есть другие более простые способы и другие площадки? Заранее большое спасибо!
https://help.mts-link.ru/ru/articles/8612830-скачать-готовую-mp4-запись

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. Приглашаем вас ознакомиться со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

По вашей же ссылке всё написано. Делаете GET запрос.
import requests

res = requests.get('https://userapi.mts-link.ru/v3/fileSystem/file/{{conversionId}}', headers={
    'X-Auth-Token': 'ваш токен',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
# не забудьте указать свой идентификатор в ссылке запроса и ваш токен
if res.status_code == 200:
    print(res.json()['downloadUrl'])

В случае правильного запроса мы получаем ответ от сервера, выглядит он так:
{
"downloadUrl": "https://events-storage.webinar.ru/...mp4"
}

Обращаемся к элементу словаря и выводим его.
